# ETL plus ELT hybrid approach: good idea or not?

Tags: apache-spark, database-design, architecture, etl, data-warehouse

### Question

*Is this a good idea, while going with ETL approach, do some last-stage aggregations as ELT (materialized views inside DW)?*

### Details

Currently we have an ETL process (data lake => data warehouse): `Nifi -> Storage [raw] -> Spark -> Storage [dl] -> Spark -> Storage [dw] -> Data Warehouse -> Power BI/Bus Users`.

`Data Warehouse` = tiny projection for Power BI/business users, no transformation logic at all. 
`Storage [dl]` layer is used for further ETL processing, DS and ML, possibly for data exploration too in future. 
`Storage [dw]` data serves only one purpose - to be loaded into our Data Warehouse.

Now suppose there are aggregation derived from `Storage [dw]` layer, those aggregations are needed only inside Data Warehouse. *Is that a good idea to move that aggreations from Spark to Data Warehouse materialized views?*

### Considerations

Data Warehouse materialized views seems to be more natural approach for those aggregations. They're easier to implement, no need to add DW uploading logic & orchestration step. But we should make a decision and go with single approach. So I'm afraid of the following things:

1. [Major] I would like to reuse some logic and cover all the logic with unit tests. In the same time I wouldn't like to add SQL unit tests framework.
2. [Medium] Unlikely, but hourly aggregations calculation may compete for resources with Power BI. Still all heavy lifting will be done by Spark.
3. [Minor] Aggregation step is not part of orchestration any more. I can't fail pipeline on view execution failure. Minor, because with SQL and structured data I think this scenario will be very uncommon.

### P.S.

Because of huge data volume, Power BI direct query to Data Warehouse performance is one of the key measures. Splitting big aggegation tables into multiple smaller is one of the ways to optimize things. So delegating creation of multiple agregations to Power BI developers would be a nice option save some development time (instead of creating a ticket to Spark team every time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take, although this is not really a SO question but I have no issue with that.

1. ELT and ELT are not complementary, rather it is one or the other approach - do you keep incorrect data around and load all data - ELT? Or cleanse and reject incorrect data aka ETL traditionally?
2. But I take your point that in the "raw" data lake you could see that as ELT minus the transformation, so it would be EL.
3. Not sure on your exact difference dw vs Data Warehouse in reality. Seems like the old DWH vs. Datamarts except that you imply Big Data setting and non-Big Data setting - your DWH is a traditional RDBMS?
4. Materialized Views cannot be too complex - if you mean ORACLE MV's. Otherwise my take is that fact level data is most flexible - Ralph Kimball - and that view layers on top have preference, unless the calculation cannot be done in a view layer. Datamarts presuppose things and mean more work ultimately degrading the Self-Service paradigm.
5. DM's were there when there were a lot of performance issues in the past that also lead to dimensional modelling, but things like Microsoft SQL Server Parallel and EXADATA put those concerns to bed.
6. Fact level data should prevail where possible. I only made things programmatically for BI that could not be easily reported on via view layer logic - e.g. bull-, bear-spread of commodity tradings per time intervals, as an example.
7. Your premise is the volume of data and use of Power BI, Spotfire, Tableau against Spark or Hive or KUDU tables. This seems to be an issue and hard to get right at times. That said the use of Hue with KUDU and parquet were super quick on one of my previous assignments. Getting Thrift Server issues resolved was not easy if memory serves correctly. OBVIATED due to clarification.
8. If the volume is too large, then basic MV aggr. are fine on data pushed to your traditional DWH. That said, the Spark agg functions are pretty simple too and can be pushed there as well. I think you can go either way, or rely on good partitioning in Hadoop (for specific querying still). In any event what you suggest as final aggr. layer in "our DWH" I see at many clients still. It serves them well, until Big Data catches up with Optimizers and replaces EXADATA et al. Try KUDU. Super fast, or parquet. OBVIATED in part due to clarification.

So, many points fine but I feel ELT and ETL are non-complementary.

Comment: thank you for your answer! There is a little clarification, sorry for making a confusion, by Storate[raw]/Storage[dl]/Storage[dw] I meant different containers of ADLS or in future Bronze/Silver/Gold areas of Databricks. We don't have Data Marts, just a single Data Warehouse (Azure Synapse). Just wanted to make question technology agnostic

Comment: currently Power BI performance issues a noticed during querying Synapse MPP (1000 DWU) on fact tables with 1 billlion+ rows. Power BI composite model (when aggregation is small) & fact table aggregations at Synapse (when aggregation > 1GB because of non-additive measures or too many slicers) are our escapes from performance issues. We considered Delta Lake performance wouldn't be enough and better to use Synapse

Comment: the oracle mv is indeed technical. ok the spark thing also in absence of the Synapse qualification is clear, i am more familiar with AWS, but clear. none the less the elt etl notion holds in my answer with the provisos

Comment: managed services, pricey.

Comment: in any event this confirms that the off loading concept is not what the cloud providers foresee, rather DL plus managed services for dwh, which was my conclusion 2 years ago.

Comment: @thebluphantom so you're suggesting to load fact tables from ADLS to Synapse, and build simple MV's in SQL, am I right?

Comment: could you please explain what did you mean by "off loading" concept? Just general wondering) you've already answered my question

Comment: First comment: With the MPP approach I would leave as is at fact level and do aggr on the fly, unless these are problematic.

Comment: Second comment: Off-loading was the HortonWorks approach on those wanting to move their SAP HANA or EXADATA DWH stuff to Hive, Impala, Parquet. But there were all sorts of issues with connecting to the Big Data sources with tableau et al. Then AWS offered Athena and all those managed services although Spark offered Drill and all that. The off loading has not been that succesful imho. What you are doing is the AZURE way like AWS. Pricey though for querying. Hope this hekps but on the other hand they have to make some money as well, although the Apache consortium gets nothing!

Comment: thank you for details!!